# Permutations algorithm (but not all possible permutations)

Tags: algorithm

I'm experiencing a problem with permutations without repetitions in programming. Here is the abstraction I'm trying to understand in order to be able to program it...

I have a list of **n** (for example 5 like below) objects:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

My purpose is to group the number from this list in triplets without repetition:

```
123
124
125
234
235
345
```

I don't want to have 132, 142, 152... and so on - I just want unique triplets of numbers to be generated.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want is combinations, not permutations. Google will yield good results with that term.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I've found what I need now, I used to search for permutations and that's why I didn't get any correct results about my problem ;)